# How to calculate elapsed time with single line sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to calculate elapsed time with SQL. I'm executing the sql from python flask backend.
My Code is here:

```sql
SELECT @d := renew_date FROM `business` WHERE b_id = 5;
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, @d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as elapsed;
```

Is there any possibility of concurrency problem? How can I test it locally?

Is there any way to write it in single line?

Comment: Why can't you just write `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, renew_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as elapsed FROM \`business\` WHERE b_id = 5;`?

Comment: @Nick, Couldn't think this way... *sigh*... Spent two hours on it. But it was this easy! Thank you!

Comment: No worries. I'm not sure this question has much value for other users so you might consider just deleting it.